# Can't connect to postrgres using Visual Studio with dotConnect

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection, devart, dotconnect

When I try to connect to DataBase, I get error: Key word doesn't support: Host.

```
        int x = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        try
        {

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString =
           Properties.Settings.Default.postgresConnectionString;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "getCount";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter param = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@k",
           SqlDbType.Int);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Tovar", x));
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string kolvo = cmd.Parameters["@k"].Value.ToString();
            con.Close();
            label1.Text = kolvo + " израсходован в количестве ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Connection String:

```
User Id=postgres;Password=8loz9fnl;Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Persist Security Info=True
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `NpgsqlConnection` (or maybe `OdbcConnection`?) instead of `SqlConnection`? SQL Server provider has `Data Source`, not `Host` by the way. Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automaticalliy instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Comment: Why dont you use  [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/)?, Just have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30989/Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-C-NET-application-An-intr)

Comment: @wingedpanther Thanks, Connection works, but I get this result "The value for the output parameter '@k" is absent in the command execution result. The name of parameter : @k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you're using devart's dotconnect for ado.net connectivity so you should import `Devart.Data.PostgreSql` and use `PgSqlConnection` instead of `sqlconnection` and `pgsqlcommand` instead of `sqlcommand`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned already, you need to use [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/). Also use imports to simplify your code. Example connection code:
import the assembly `using Npgsql;` then to get a connection and open it

```
using (var  conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.postgresConnectionString)) 
{ 
    // you other code here
}
```

This way your resources are managed automatically and you don't need to call the close method, also you need to change the type of command as @wingedpanther mentions. Reading a good tutorial or the docs mentioned will help a lot.
Also you need to fix your connection string as:

```
Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;Password=8loz9fnl;Database=postgres;Persist Security Info=True
```

And avoid putting your actual username and password.